# Relative Path in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, relative-path

I have relative path for header in my cpp class. Loading the same with Xcode.

```
My path is ../../common/graphics/green_image.PNG
```

This is the path given in the cpp file but, images are not loadding.

Now I am using the images by removing the path ie, directly using `green_image.PNG`

In Build Settings HeaderSearch path given , ${SDKROOT}/common

But, it is not working. How can I solve the problem.

Comment: Lets us know when you decide to stop editing this question. Already deleted two answers cause they didn't match the question anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
${SRCROOT}/common
```

That would search your source root (/common); you've got it set for the SDK root.